# Nodejs running as a service with nssm in windows can't access a network drive

Tags: node.js, networking, driver, nssm

I have a nodejs program that accesses files via fs in a network drive. When I run this program from the console everything goes fine.
When the same program runs as a service wrapped with nssm (https://nssm.cc/) it returns an error "ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir".
I've try different solutions, including running the service as an administrator user with all permissions, but the error continues.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ENOENT` means file/directory not found. please share stack trace (error log) it will have which file it was trying to access.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your interest. It's not a file it's a network unit mapped to the computer where the node service is running. As I explained it is accessible if I run the program directly from the console (with node sercer.js for example). But when I run it as a service wrapped with nssm I received that error with no additional information, but a reference to the directory I want to access. The complete message is "{"message":"DAEMON ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'V:\\PreAlbaranCliente\\ALBARANES'","level":"error"}".